# По окончании цикла выводим alert()

Tags: python, циклы

Есть такая логика:

1. Вписываем название канала в поиск
2. Заходим в канал
3. Оставляем комментарий
4. Делаем снова но вписываем уже следующее название канала

Как возможно по окончании цикла (когда кликер прошёлся по всем названиями каналов) показать какое-то сообщение? (p.s список каналов получаю как не странно, в виде списка)

Примерный код:

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui as pg

def spamming():
    ''' Переходим по каналам и оставляем комментарии '''
        
for i in range(len(channels_urls)):
    if цикл закончил работу:
        pg.alert("Я прошёлся по всем каналам успешно!")
    else:
        pg.moveTo(0, 0) # сбиваем позицию курсора мыши
        pg.moveRel(100, 50)
        time.sleep(duration)
        pg.click(clicks=3)
        time.sleep(duration)
        pg.typewrite(['backspace'])
        time.sleep(duration)
        keyboard.write(channels_urls[i])
        time.sleep(duration)
        pg.moveRel(100, 100)
        time.sleep(3)
        pg.click(clicks=1)
        time.sleep(5)
        pg.moveRel(500, 800)
        pg.click(clicks=1)
        time.sleep(3)
        pg.moveRel(0, 50)
        pg.click(clicks=3)
        pg.typewrite(['backspace'])
        keyboard.write(message)
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Хмм... А что вам мешает вывести сообщение после тела цикла?

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: не-а не получилось

Comment: код того, что не получилось, где?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну если `channels_urls` - это список, то можно попробовать так:

```
while channels_urls:
    #...
    keyboard.write(channels_urls.pop())
    #...
pg.alert("Я прошёлся по всем каналам успешно!")
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное

Answer (score 1):

```
    for i in range(len(channels_urls)):
        pg.moveTo(0, 0) # сбиваем позицию курсора мыши
        pg.moveRel(100, 50)
        time.sleep(duration)
        pg.click(clicks=3)
        time.sleep(duration)
        pg.typewrite(['backspace'])
        time.sleep(duration)
        keyboard.write(channels_urls[i])
        time.sleep(duration)
        pg.moveRel(100, 100)
        time.sleep(3)
        pg.click(clicks=1)
        time.sleep(5)
        pg.moveRel(500, 800)
        pg.click(clicks=1)
        time.sleep(3)
        pg.moveRel(0, 50)
        pg.click(clicks=3)
        pg.typewrite(['backspace'])
        keyboard.write(message)
        time.sleep(10)
    else:
        pg.alert("Я прошёлся по всем каналам успешно!")
```

Попробуйте так.